# Nested Sum( ) query is not working in mysql

Tags: nested, sum

i'm having a problem in calculating total bill of a ptient. I have three tables named as "test", "pharmacy", "check".

Columns in `test` are:

```
patient_ID 
testname
rate
```

Columns in `pharmacy` are:

```
patient_ID
medicineDescription
qty
rate
```

Columns in `check` are:

```
patient_ID 
doctorID
fees
date
```

I have a table `Bill` that will store total amount of a patient.

```
patient_ID
amount
date
```

I have used the following query. But it's giving the following error.

```
$result = mysqli_query($data,  "SELECT patient_ID, (SUM(pharmacy.qty*pharmacy.rate ) + SUM(test.rate) + SUM(check.fees)) 
     AS total FROM pharmacy, test, check  WHERE patient_ID= '$pID'" );
```

Comment: You have there a typo, 3x `(`, but only 2x `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct query should be, closing bracket was missing at the end of subquery (`... AS total FROM pharmacy**)**`):

```
$result = mysqli_query ($data, "SELECT patient_ID, 
                                       (SUM(pharmacy.qty*pharmacy.rate ) + SUM(test.rate) + SUM(check.fees)) AS total FROM pharmacy), 
                                       test, 
                                       check  
                                WHERE patient_ID= '$pID'" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three tables in your `from` clause, but with no join condition - this means you're pairing each row with all the other rows, which is obviously not what you intended. One way to handle this is to use proper `join`s:

```
SELECT p.patient_id, pharmacy_sum + test_sum + fees_sum AS total
FROM   (SELECT   patient_id, SUM(qty * rate) AS pharmacy_sum
        FROM     pharmacy
        WHERE    patient_ID= '$pID'
        GROUP BY patient_id) p
JOIN   (SELECT patient_id, SUM(rate) AS test_sum
        FROM     test
        WHERE    patient_ID= '$pID'
        GROUP BY patient_id) t ON p.patient_id_id = t.patient_id
JOIN   (SELECT   patient_id, SUM(fees) AS fees_sum
        FROM     check
        WHERE    patient_ID= '$pID'
        GROUP BY patient_id) c ON p.patient_id_id = c.patient_id
```